# Diferença entre "Function Operator" e "Function Factory"

Tags: r, terminologia, programação-funcional

Ao [capítulo 11](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html) do livro [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/), o autor define *Function Operator* como:

> *A function operator is a function that takes one (or more) functions as input and returns a function as output.*

**Tradução Google Translate**

*Um operador de função é uma função que recebe uma (ou mais) funções como entrada e retorna uma função como saída.*

A minha dúvida com esta definição é em relação ao conceito de *Function Factory*:

> *A factory for making new functions*

**Tradução Google Translate**

*Uma fábrica para fazer novas funções.*

Mas, uma *Function Factory* também recebe funções e retorna uma função como saída:

```
fun <- function(x){
  c(sum(x), mean(x), sd(x))
}
```

`fun` é a função retornada.

Então,

- qual é a diferença entre *Function Operator* e *Function Factory*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O @Ailton está correto quando diz

> *operador* é um caso particular de fábrica.

Mas vou ilustrar melhor essa idéia. Há fábricas de funções que podem ser de diversos tipos, vou mostrar fábricas que são do tipo operador e fábricas que não o são.

### Fábricas - o caso geral

A motivação de uma *fábrica de funções* é fazer uma metafunção, ou seja, uma função que cria outras funções. Com ela somos capazes de abstrair o processo de criação de funções semelhantes.

Um ótimo exemplo de fábricas dentro do [r](/questions/tagged/r) são as funções `color*` do pacote [leaflet](/questions/tagged/leaflet). Essa funções retornam funções que mapeiam valor em cores.

```
verdes <- leaflet::colorNumeric("Greens", c(0, 4))
args(verdes)
# function (x) 
# NULL
```

A fábrica nos permite criar uma paleta de cores de forma muito semelhante para o vermelho, por exemplo.

```
vermelhos <- leaflet::colorNumeric("Reds", c(0,4))
verdes(2)
# [1] "#74C476"
vermelhos(2)
# [1] "#FB6A4A"
```

Veja, contudo, que a definição geral de fábrica até agora nos permite incluir nela quaisquer funções que retornem uma função, sem incluir restrições ou casos especiais. a `colorNumeric`, por exemplo, usa textos e números para criar sua função.

## Operador funcional - o caso específico

É possível pensarmos num caso específico de fábrica. Um tipo que recebe funções para construir a função retornada. Essa ideia nos permite criar abstrações para pensarmos sobre como modificar as funções recebidas como argumentos.

Um operador funcional não precisa necessariamente operar **apenas** funções, ele pode receber argumentos de outros tipos também. É necessário, contudo, que receba ao menos uma função dentro seus argumentos.

No capítulo do Hadley Wickham citado ele elenca quatro tipos de operadores:

1. De comportamento
2. De saída (output)
3. De entrada (input)
4. De combinação

Um exemplo seria criar um próprio `pipe`.

```
pipe <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)

  function(x) {
    for (i in seq_along(dots)) {
      x <- dots[[i]](x)
    }
    x
  }
}

soma_raizes <- pipe(sqrt, sum)
soma_raizes(c(1, 4, 9))
# [1] 6
```

Bons exemplos de operadores funcionais no [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) são `purrr::safely()` e `purrr::quietly()`.

Answer (score 5):

Não estou dando uma definição formal, mas você tem razão em perceber que os dois conceitos são relacionados.
Neste caso, *operador* é um caso particular de *fábrica*.

Em Matemática, a expressão *operador* é usada para algo que associa elementos em um mesmo conjunto. Por exemplo, no R, `+` é uma função que pode ser chamada assim:

> `+`(2, 3)

Sendo uma função que aceita argumentos numéricos e que retorna um valor numérico, ela também pode ser chamada de operador numérico.

Analogamente, um operador funcional não deixa de ser uma fábrica, mas tem como argumentos apenas funções e é algo que retorna uma função.