# O que é e para que serve uma função anônima em R?

Tags: r, função-anônima

- O que é uma função anônima? E por que pode ser chamada de `função lambda`?
- Qual é a utilidade de uma função anônima na linguagem `R`?
- Onde ela pode ser aplicada (por exemplo, pode ser aplicada em [function operators](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356959/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-function-operator-e-function-factory))?

Comment: Acho que boa parte das respostas estão neste [link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html).

Comment: Fica a dica aí pra quem quiser preparar um conteúdo a respeito disso em português : )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***O que é função anônima em R?***

- Uma **função anônima *Anonymous Function*** (também conhecida como expressão *lambda*) é uma definição de função que
  não está vinculada a um identificador. Ou seja, é uma função criada e
  usada, mas nunca atribuída a uma variável. Ou seja, R não possui uma sintaxe especial para criar uma função nomeada: quando você cria uma função, usa o operador de atribuição regular para atribuir um nome. Se você optar por não atribuir um nome à função, receberá uma **função anônima**.

***E por que pode ser chamada de função lambda***?

- **Expressões lambda** são funções sem nome dadas como valores constantes. Eles podem aparecer em qualquer lugar que qualquer outra constante, mas são tipicamente escritos como um parâmetro para alguma outra função.
- A palavra "**lambda**" ou "**expressões lambda**" geralmente se
  refere a funções anônimas. Então, nesse sentido, um lambda é um tipo
  de função (função anônima), mas nem toda função é um lambda (ou seja,
  funções nomeadas não são geralmente chamadas de lambdas).
- **Logo, funçôes anônimas em multas linguagens são tratadas como lambda.**

***Qual é a utilidade de uma função anônima na linguagem R?***

*Exemplo simples de função anônima em r:*

```
# Sintaxe de função anônima
(function(x) x * 10)(10)

# equivalente (normal)
fun<-function(x) x * 10

fun(10)
```

- Como a sintaxe acima indica, você está fazendo tudo de uma só vez: a
  declaração e a chamada em uma declaração de linha. Portanto, apesar
  de não ser transparente ao lê-lo, ele é autocontido e você o usa
  porque não quer definir mais nenhuma outra função em algum outro
  script atual (ou em um script externo): você está lidando com um
  simples cálculo quando for necessário, e você provavelmente não o
  usará em nenhum outro lugar do seu código, portanto, não vale a pena
  lembrá-lo.